# is it possible to configure an instance of the "context" class through construction?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I made a "context" class called "ApplicationDbContext" which takes necessary information for configuration through construction:

```
namespace SportsStore.Models
{
public class ApplicationDbContext:DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> 
options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

 }
}
```

and then I registered this context class in startup class to connect to my database using the AddDbContext method:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
            options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:SportStoreProducts:ConnectionStrings"]));
        services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
        services.AddMvc();


    }
```

and finally, made a class called seedata to use "ApplicationDbContext" class which already configured to save my model object in the database :

```
public class SeedData
{
    public static void EnsurePopulated(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = 
 app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
        context.Database.Migrate();
```

Now my question is that how we can configurate the Construction, so that instead of accessing the already configured ApplicationDbContext object ( through accessing IserviceProvider)

```
ApplicationDbContext context = 
 app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

how we can have an instance of ApplicationDbContext (here: context) through construction like:

```
ApplicationDbContext context=new ApplicationDbContext();
```

what should I put inside construction parameter to have the same result as above code? and in any case, do I need to 100% register the context class "ApplicationDbContext"?

Answer (score 1):

You can add empty constructor and `override OnConfiguring` method:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    //another code...

    public ApplicationDbContext()
    {}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)            
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }
}
```